# SharePoint 2013 - New BI Semantic Model Connection - Cannot connect to the server or database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssas, sharepoint-2013, powerview

All on one machine I have:

- Windows 2012
- SQL Server 2012 with SSAS running in Tabular mode
- A SSAS Tabular model created for the AdventureWorksDW database
- SharePoint 2013

Using Excel 2013, I am able to connect to the SSAS Tabular model with no issues.

When I attempt to create a "New BI Semantic Model Connection" in SharePoint 2013 to connect to the SSAS Tabular model, I get this error:
"Cannot connect to the server or database."

I can click "Save the link file without connection validation", however the saved connection is also not usable by Power View.

When I get the above error, I also see an "Audit Failure" event in Windows Event Viewer for the user "NT SERVICE\MSSQLServerOLAPService".

All SharePoint services are running as the local Administrator account.  That account has been made an administrator of the SSRS server and assigned a role in the SSAS Tabular model.  I have done the same for the "NT SERVICE\MSSQLServerOLAPService" account, with no luck.

Are there other security configuration settings I have missed somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Right click Analisis Server properties then choose security add service account as a server admin